# Software tools for options investing

Tags: options, software

Are there free or inexpensive software tools to assist with common computations or Monte Carlo analysis in dealing with investing in options on common stocks?

I probably know enough to write something really simple & basic for myself, but I'm afraid of getting the math wrong, or of being too simplistic.

The kinds of things I'm looking for, are tools to answer the questions I stated in my other question " [Options for the intelligent but inexperienced](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/options-for-the-intelligent-but-inexperienced) "

Answer (score 3):

Also check out OptionsOracle from http://www.samoasky.com/ . Free, and even downloads data automatically.

Many broker packages (ThinkOrSwim for instance) allow you to view option greeks, comparative valuation charts, implied volatility smiles and so on.

Comment: +1 for listing a few software options, but SamOasky did not work for me. It did not load any data.

Comment: Strange - have used it on four pcs without an issue (but with Indian data only). Which exchanges are you downloading data for? will check

Answer (score 0):

Try this software package. I don't have experience with options trading, but the software seems legitimate.

http://www.mgsoft.ru/en/products_options_calculator.aspx